# How to stop a Linux service as soon as java application completes its execution

Tags: linux, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, exception

Background:

I have developed a spring boot application(i.e myapp) which can run infinite time based on the input (if the input is true it runs infinite times else runs only once) given from configuration file(application.yml).

This application runs as a linux service(i.e myService.sh) on a remote server.

`sh myService.sh start` > will start the servie
`sh myService.sh stop` > will stop the service

When the service starts the spring boot application gets triggered and perform the execution

Note the script file content which trigger the jar/application.
`$/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-11.0.19.0.7-1.el7_9.x86_64/bin/java -jar myapp.jar  -Dspring.config.location=application.yml`

case 1:
when the service is started and the input given for  myapp.jar is 'true' then the application suppose to execute infinite time and service is status should be running until explicitly stop the service.
case 2:
When the service is started and the input given for myapp.jar is 'false' then the application is completing the one time execution. but the status of the service is still running.

Expectation for case 2:
When the jar execution is completed then the service also should stop running.

I have done the online research to stop the current running linux services using java and to safe exit form java application, it is not much useful.

Your response is appreciated..

Suggestions in how to achieve the expection

Comment: I could find the solution, you can refer the below link 
*https://foojay.io/today/clean-shutdown-of-spring-boot-applications/*